# GetBoundingClientRect doesn't work outside the window

Tags: javascript, css, coordinates, getcomputedstyle, getboundingclientrect

I am making a script that should measure distances in a post. For example, if i have three posts:

- Post 1: *two lines of text, then the image that I want to see.*
- Post 2: *Just the image that I want to see.*
- Post 3: *The image I want to see Followed by two lines.*

**The reason I want this, is because I think Tumblr displays too much nonsense in their discriptions. I am making a chrome extension that will crop all the nonsense around images so that you have to scroll less. on every posts will apear a button to see the whole post.**

As of today, it works great! With `getBoundingClientRect` I can get the top, left, bottom and right offset from the window. There is just 1 problem. I can not do it for all the posts on a page right away, because if a post is 700px or more away of the visible part of the document, the part you're viewing in the browser, all the values provided by GBCR will be 0.

These values are not valid, and are probably zero because the post isn't rendered on screen. And I could make my extension try to get the dimensions if I scroll, so that when a post gets in the visible part of the window, it is processed. But this doesnt have my preference. This would mean my JS functions have to be *triggered* every time a user scrolls, which is bad practice. I much rather start my functions when the dom is loaded, so if new posts are added, the functions will be triggered.

---

My question for you is the following: Is there a workaround to make sure the function GBCR works when the post is not rendered on screen. Or is there a way that I can get the Coordinats of an element with `getComputedStyle` (without going through all the elements)?

Comment: Great question! Read an entire page and calculate positions of the elements on the page (document-based) irrespective of a "window". I've found offsettop offsetleft, and on this page there is a method for calculating document positions - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html - I'll keep snooping around.

Comment: This is indeed a possible way. However, it has to move up the Tree, which means it is slower than GBCR